# Dataframe to GRID in PDF using ReportLab. How could I breakline in a column in the grid

Tags: python, reportlab

I need a breakline in the Grid, because the value of a column is too big to put in PDF:

[image]

My Code:

```
for i, (_, rowCampos) in enumerate(dfBaseCampos.iterrows()):
    dados.append([str(rowCampos['CAMPO']),
    str(rowCampos['DESC_CAMPO']),
    str(rowCampos['TIPO_CAMPO'])])

tabela = Table(dados, style=([
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black, None, (2, 2, 1)),
    ('BACKGROUND', (2, 0), (2, 0), colors.lightcyan),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (0, 0), colors.lightcyan),
    ('BACKGROUND', (1, 0), (1, 0), colors.lightcyan),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 5),
    ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black)
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Flowable object like `Paragraph`.

```
l1 = Paragraph("Hello python", styles['Normal'])
```

This solution works for me:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
for i, (_, rowCampos) in enumerate(dfBaseCampos.iterrows()):
    l1 = Paragraph(str(rowCampos['CAMPO']), styles['Normal'])
    l2 = Paragraph(str(rowCampos['DESC_CAMPO']), styles['Normal'])
    l3 = Paragraph(str(rowCampos['TIPO_CAMPO']), styles['Normal'])
    dados.append([l1, l2, l3])

tabela =Table(dados)
tabela.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black, None, (2, 2, 1)),
    ('BACKGROUND', (2, 0), (2, 0), colors.lightcyan),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (0, 0), colors.lightcyan),
    ('BACKGROUND', (1, 0), (1, 0), colors.lightcyan),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 5),
    ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black)
]))
```